# Ansible how to push local image to private registry

Tags: docker, ansible

I have a private registry on my server.

After which, I tried tag image and push it by ansible.

```
- name: Tag to repository to a private registry and push it
  docker_image:
    name: dwf/test_sample
    repository: registry.dwf.com/dwf/test_sample
    state: present
```

Image `dwf/test_sample` is local image on my laptop. But it tries pull from DockerHub :|, and I received this error:

```
"msg": "Error pulling dwf/test_sample - code: None message: Error: image dwf/test_sample not found"}
```

How to use local image or disable `pull` when `tag` and `push` image ?

Pls suggest a specific solution. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The examples in the docs (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_image_module.html) give some guidance:

```
- name: Push image to registry
  docker_image:
    name: test_sample
    repository: registry.dwf.com:5000/test_sample
    push: yes
```

For this to work you require the image `test_sample` to be in your local docker instance.

Answer (score 0):

create a local image with the same repository and tag that will be in the

```
remote registry
- name: "tag the image"
  docker_image:
    name: "local-image:tagname"
    repository: "reponame:tagname"

- name: "push to docker registry"
  docker_image:
    name: "reponame:tagname"
    push: yes
```